# In Windows 10 can ProgramData/.../SystemData Folder be emptied of contents without consequence?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, lock-screen

> - Would like to know if I can safely delete the contents of the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData folder, all folders and files there in.
> - It seems that these folders may be auto generated, and mainly are named by User Account Security Identifier's, so deleting them may be harmless.
> - Or at least is it safe to delete all files with the del /s star dot star command leaving the sub-folder structure.
> - The purpose is to flush the cache for the lock-screen stored at this location so that the default images at C:\Windows\Web\Screen will come into effect.

Example Code; delete folders and file contents:

```
RD C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData /S /Q
```

Example Code; Delete only files within folders:

```
Del /s /q C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\*.*
```

***Current Research:***

[How do you delete all the files but not the directories in a folder?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-delete-all-the-files-but-not-the-directories-in-a-folder)

[SU - Retrieve Custom Windows 10 Lock Screen Image](https://superuser.com/questions/1376513/retrieve-custom-windows-10-lock-screen-image/1376530#1376530)

[SU - How to override the default Windows 10 lock screen image for all users?](https://superuser.com/a/1385317/900431)

[Pastebin - Set Lockscreen for windows 10](https://pastebin.com/F8TXFhiN)

[ss64 - RD](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)

[ss64 - Del](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In regards to: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData`
>
> *Changes to this folder **can corrup**t Windows Spotlight from working
>   again please backup system before trying to make various
>   offline hacks for the lock screen and login screen.*

**How to use Task Scheduler to run System Task in Windows 10**

> It seems that this location is used for storing lockscreen cache
>   organised by user, deleting the images in the location is used by
>   thewindowsclud, while deleting the folders in the directory is only
>   found in one pastebin hack solution.
>
> I have not found any way to easily take ownership of the folder and revert the permissions so have instead found a simple way to run the task as System.

1. Save a batch file ClearSystemDataCache.cmd with the following (this relates to above question, otherwise make script to be run by system):

   `Del /s /q C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\*.*`
2. Run taskschedular as admin

   - Name the task --> Clear SystemData Cache *(or name of task)
   - Change User or Group --> Advanced --> Find Now --> Scroll Down Select 'System' --> OK --> OK
   - Tick 'Run with Highest Privileges'
   - Under actions tab browse and select ClearSystemDataCache.cmd
   - Set up an automatic triggers under triggers tab, such as on unlock.
   - Click --> OK --> OK
3. Now can right click on task and 'Run' or wait for set trigger.
4. This task can be also exported as an xml file and imported into other computers.

`No need to use takeown or icacls to make these system changes.`

**Reading:**

[SO How do you run CMD.exe under the Local System Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78691/7811302)

[Edugeek - 10 holding onto cached lock screen images?](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-10/174406-w10-holding-onto-cached-lock-screen-images.html)

[Thewindowsclub - How to remove Lock Screen images history from Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-lock-screen-images-history-windows-10)

[Microsoft Forum - LockScreen Cache not updating](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5bb1e221-ce3b-4d9c-bf85-38687724d840/lockscreen-cache-not-updating?forum=win10itprogeneral)

[Pastebin - Set Lockscreen for windows 10](https://pastebin.com/F8TXFhiN)

[SU - Is there a way in which I can use takeown to apply ownership to every directory on the drive?](https://superuser.com/a/813881/900431)

**Questions:**

[SU - How to use Icals & Takeown to make changes and reset in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1414989/900431)

[SU - 'Access Denied' how to revert permissions - icacls and takeown](https://superuser.com/q/1415188/900431)